# Python Matplotlib: creating a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

Write code that reads the contents of the test file "T1" and records the minimum Hamming distance between a crib and the translation of "T1" with a random dictionary for 10,000 random dictionaries. Use  matplotlib.pyplot.hist to draw a histogram of the results.

I already have the functions that record the minimum hamming distance, does the translation of "T1", and also makes random dictionaries but I'm not sure how to use this to make a histogram using matplotlib for 10,000 dictionaries.

I was thinking

```
plt.hist(min_ham_dist("crib",trans_cipher(T1,rand_dict())))
```

should be used somewhere since these are the names of my functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to generate the array or list of the minimum hamming distance values. For example (tested in [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/)):

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##### This block is only dummy methods so that is compatible with your example
def rand_dict(): return None
def trans_cipher(a, b): return None
def min_ham_dist(a, b): return random.randint(0, 1000)
T1 = None
#####

arr = [min_ham_dist("crib",trans_cipher(T1,rand_dict())) for i in range(10000)] # This is the important point
plt.hist(arr, bins=20)
plt.show()
```

In this case I'm using List Comprehension ([PEP 202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)) to quickly build a list of the random values. The result should be something like this:

[image: dummy histogram using matplotlib hist method]

Comment: and can I add labels but just doing plt.xlabel('Minimum Hamming Distance') and plt.ylabel('Number of Simulations')?

Comment: Yes, but that would have been faster to test yourself than asking here.

Comment: Also, for some reason there is 2 different coloured plots on the histogram, is there a way to just make it one?

Comment: That is probably because your input is a list of two lists (or something similar). Print the lists to the screen and check what you are trying to plot (make list comprehensions of 10 elements instead of 10 000 to be easier to debug).